# What is a Binary File?

Tags: php, binaryfiles

In the following context I would like to know what a binary file means.

> The mode argument of the fopen() function can also take value b to indicate that the openend file should be treated as a binary file.

Another excerpt from the same text block:

> The default mode of fopen() function has been set to binary for all platforms that distinguishes between text and binary file.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file

Comment: If you open it with a text editor and see garbage, then it's likely a binary file.

Comment: In the  context of the PHP file functions it means that linebreaks are not converted from/to CR `\r` - LF `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary file is a *possibly non-text* file such as images, videos or zips... anything could be read as a binary. Compiled code is another example of this.

A binary file is anything a Computer could interpret and you by just reading it cannot.

*Note: You could cast a text file as a binary too, if you want.*